# Add restriction to a domain

Tags: php

I build 2 website with a single codebase that have the same database and deployed in two different web sites.

I would like to restrict another domain 2 from accessing domain 1 and add function that if the domain is domain 2 replace it to domain 1, but i dont know what function to add

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] !== 'abc.com'){
    //add funtion to restrict domain 2
}
elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'cde.com');{
    // add function here to change domain 2 to domain 1
}
?>
```

Comment: I don't understand what behaviour you want to achieve. What does it mean to restrict a domain? Please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I want a function that if does not match the domain im targeting , change the domain.

Comment: You want to make an HTTP redirect? How would the behaviour be from the outside, without looking at the code?